# Java replace ascii char

Tags: java

I have a file (prueba.txt) and I would like to replace ascii characters 0xE1 (á) for 0x14, 0xE9 (é) for 0x15, 0xF3 (ó) for 0x16 ... In string is possible with `String.replace()` but it is a char.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Reemplazar {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Scanner archivo = new Scanner(new File("prueba.txt"));

            while(archivo.hasNextLine()) {
                String frase = archivo.nextLine();

                for (int i = 0; i < frase.length(); i++) {
                    char current = frase.charAt(i);

                    if  (current == 0xe1) {
                        System.out.println("contiene la á: '"+frase+"'");
                     }

                    if  (current == 0xe9) {
                        System.out.println("contiene es la é: '"+frase+"'");
                    }

                }
          }
     }
}
```

I guess this code is much improved, but ...

Greetings.

Comment: What is the character set and encoding of your text file? Your mention of ASCII is confusing as well as the format of your UTF-16 code units. Why not write them as '\u00e1' or 'á'? All Java String and char are UTF-16.

Comment: is true is a bit confusing, sorry, the encoding is ANSI, the text contains some special characters, such as á, é, ñ ... I want to change these special characters by other characters ►, ☼, ◄

Greetings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First read the text file, then replace the characters.

**Reading**

A text file has some specific character set and encoding. You must know exactly what it is or that is definitely the system default ANSI character set and encoding. ANSI is not one specific encoding.

But, since you said ANSI, you probably meant the system default. The `Scanner` constructor you used is for Java's default. You can reasonably assume that Java's default correctly matches the system default.

**Replacing characters**

All "characters" in Java's `String`, `char` and `Character` datatypes and in an analyzed Java source file are UTF-16 code units, one or two of which encode a Unicode codepoint. Unescaped literal strings and characters are going to be in the encoding of the source file. (Of course, that *should* be UTF-8.) Regardless, if you type it, see it, save it and compile it with the same encoding, the characters will be what you think they are.

So, once you have text in a string, you can replace, replace, replace, like this:

```
frase
    .replace('á', '►')
    .replace('é', '☼')
    .replace('ñ', '◄')
```

or

```
frase
    .replace('\u00E1', '\u25B6')
    …
```

BTW—0x14, 0x15, 0x16 are the encodings for  ►, ☼, ◄ in the one encoding for the [OEM437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) character set.

If you'd rather iterate through the elements of the String, you could do it by each UTF-16 code unit, such as using `charAt`. That would work best if all your text was characters that UTF-16 encodes with just one code unit. Given that your file encoding is one of the ANSI character sets for a European language, that is likely the case. Or, you can iterate with a codepoint-aware technique as seen in the Java documentation on [CharSequence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#codePoints--).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, but frase.Replace () does not change the values, this is the code.
        while(archivo.hasNextLine()) {
             String frase = archivo.nextLine();
            char[] letras = frase.toCharArray();
             for (int i = 0; i < letras.length; ++i) {
               switch (letras[i]) {
                 case 0xE1:
                   frase.replace ((char) 0xE1, (char) 0x14);
                  break;
               }
             }
             fichero.write(frase+"\n");         
Greetings.

Comment: Strings are immutable. Replace returns a new String. My examples are expressions so assign the result as you will.

Comment: Understand, it has its logic. Now it works, thanks.

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

It is even better that it is `char`, because you can do something like this:

`yourStringToReplace.replace(0xe1);`

`char` is an `integer` that is threated like a character insteed of a number (simply speaking)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but does nothing, I am using

liena.replace ((char) 0xE1, (char) 0x14);

and it does not work.

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

this replaces the characters and creates a new file "nueva_prueba.txt" with the changed text

```
public class Reemplazar {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedWriter out;

        File f = new File("nueva_prueba.txt");
        f.createNewFile();

        out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));


        Scanner archivo = new Scanner(new File("prueba.txt"));

        while(archivo.hasNextLine()) {
            String frase = archivo.nextLine();

            for (int i = 0; i < frase.length(); i++) {
                char current = frase.charAt(i);

                switch(current)
                {

                    case 0xe1:
                        System.out.println("contiene la á: '"+frase+"'");
                        frase = frase.replace((char) 0xe1, (char) 0x14);
                        System.out.println("nova frase: "+frase); 
                        break;

                    case 0xe9:
                        System.out.println("contiene la é: '"+frase+"'");
                        frase = frase.replace((char) 0xe9, (char) 0x15);
                        System.out.println("nova frase: "+frase); 
                        break;

                    case 0xf3:
                        System.out.println("contiene la ó: '"+frase+"'");
                        frase = frase.replace((char) 0xf3, (char) 0x16);
                        System.out.println("nova frase: "+frase); 
                        break;

                        //... outros / others

                    default:
                        break;
                }


            }

            try{

                out.write(frase);
                out.newLine();

            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        archivo.close();
        out.close();

    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Raúl Puro Can you mark the answer as "Accepted" please? =)

Comment: its solution and the solution of Tom Blodget, are good, but I read before that of Tom Blodget, I would much appreciate your response, but I can not make two, sorry.

Greetings.